# Swift 4.2 : How to select/deselect multiple marker on google map

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm implementing multiple markers on google map using swift in iOS. I've successfully placed all the markers on the map and can select the marker using 'didTap marker'method. But I'm unable to deselect it. When user select on one marker than the rest of the markers should be deselected.

```
extension MapVC {
    // Mark:- Create Marker and set position
    fileprivate func setMarkerOnMap() {
        if self.markerArray.count != 0 {
            for i in 0...self.markerArray.count - 1 {
                let data = self.markerArray[i]
                guard let lat = data.lat else {
                    return
                }
                guard let lon = data.long else {
                    return
                }           
                let camera: GMSCameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: Double(lat)!, longitude: Double(lon)!, zoom: zoomLevel)
                showMarker(position: camera.target, index: i)
            }
        }
    }

      // Mark:- Show marker on map
         fileprivate func showMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D, inde x: Int) {
            let marker = GMSMarker()
             marker.position = position
             marker.icon = UIImage(named: "marker-unselected-icon")
             marker.accessibilityLabel = "\(index)" // get index from array when click on each marker to identify
             marker.map = self.mapView
         }
     }
     //MARK - Map
     extension MapVC: GMSMapViewDelegate {
         // MARK:- DidTap marker 
         func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker)->      Bool {
             if let markerLbl = marker.accessibilityLabel{
                 index = Int(markerLbl)
             }
            if marker != self.userMarker{
               marker.icon = UIImage(named: "marker-selected-icon")
               self.restaurantDetailView.isHidden = false
                self.distanceView.isHidden = true
               self.infoView.isHidden = true
           }
              var isReturn = true
             mapView.selectedMarker = nil

        if self.markerArray.count != 0 {
            for i in 0...markerArray.count - 1 {
                if i == index {
                    let storeInfo = markerArray[i]
                    storeInfo.isSelected = !storeInfo.isSelected
                    self.destinationLat = Double(storeInfo.lat!)!
                    self.destinationLng =  Double(storeInfo.long!)!
                     marker.icon = UIImage(named: "marker-selected-icon")
                    markerArray[i] = storeInfo
                } else {
                    marker.icon = UIImage(named: "marker-unselected-icon")
                    let storeInfo = markerArray[i]
                    storeInfo.isSelected = false
                    markerArray[i] = storeInfo
                }
            }
        } else {
            mapView.selectedMarker = nil
            isReturn = true
            return isReturn
        }
        return isReturn
    }
}
```

I'm changing the selected marker image in did tap method but unfortunately, it is not working. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1):

When user want to select one marker and want to deselect all the other markers then following code would be usefull.

**To Deselect all Marker on Map:**

```html
for (marker in self.markerArray) {
  self.mapview.selectedMarker = nil
}
```

**To Select Marker on Map:**

```html
self.mapView.selectedMarker = self.userMarker
```